# WordPress хук после обновления/добавления мета-данных

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть пост-тайп мероприятий. Сами посты на моём сайте можно добавлять напрямую с фронта, реализация через AJAX. Плюс к самому посту после его создания добавляются мета поля (дата начала мероприятия, название клуба и т.д.): wp_insert_post -> update_post_meta

Я хочу сделать, чтобы каждый раз, при добавлении новой записи с фронта, был запрос, который забирает даты мероприятий **по значению другого мета-поля (event_club)** и сохранял результат в БД через set_transient. При сохранении опции, в ключе указано название мета-поля "event_club"

Приведённый ниже код работает, однако только когда пост обновляется через админку. Мне же нужно, чтобы он срабатывал всякий раз, когда добавляется новый пост через фронт-часть сайта.

```
function grz_event_updated( $post_ID, $post_after, $post_before ) {
    global $wpdb;

    // Получаем название клуба мероприятия
    $event_club = get_post_meta( !is_object($post_ID) ? $post_ID : $post_ID->ID, 'event_club', true );
    $meta_key   = 'start_date';
    $post_type  = 'event';

    // Запрос для получения даты начала всех мероприятий
    $start_date = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "
                                SELECT DISTINCT pm.meta_value FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
                                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p ON p.ID = pm.post_id
                                INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS mt1 ON ( p.ID = mt1.post_id )
                                WHERE pm.meta_key = %s
                                AND ( ( mt1.meta_key = 'event_club'
                                AND mt1.meta_value = %s ) ) 
                                AND p.post_type = %s ", $meta_key, $event_club, $post_type ), ARRAY_A );

    // Замена пробелов в названии поля и перевод в нижний регистр 
    $event_club = str_replace( ' ', '', $event_club );
    $event_club = strtolower( $event_club );

    // Формирование названия ключа
    $key        = 'grz_competitions_years_' . strtolower( $event_club );

    // Добавление опции в БД
    set_transient( $key, $start_date, 0 );
}
add_action( 'post_updated', 'grz_event_updated', 10, 3 );
```

Пробовал аналогичную реализацию через хук "save_post", но видимо он срабатывает до того, как обновляются мета-поля у поста, поэтому значение и ключ у transient пустое.

Через хук "updated_post_meta" упорно не хочет работать :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'grz_event_updated', 999, 3 );

function grz_event_updated( $post_ID, $post, $update ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( $update ) {
        return;
    }

    // Получаем название клуба мероприятия
    $event_club = get_post_meta( !is_object($post_ID) ? $post_ID : $post_ID->ID, 'event_club', true );
    $meta_key   = 'start_date';
    $post_type  = 'event';

    // Запрос для получения даты начала всех мероприятий
    $start_date = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "
                                SELECT DISTINCT pm.meta_value FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
                                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p ON p.ID = pm.post_id
                                INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS mt1 ON ( p.ID = mt1.post_id )
                                WHERE pm.meta_key = %s
                                AND ( ( mt1.meta_key = 'event_club'
                                AND mt1.meta_value = %s ) ) 
                                AND p.post_type = %s ", $meta_key, $event_club, $post_type ), ARRAY_A );

    // Замена пробелов в названии поля и перевод в нижний регистр 
    $event_club = str_replace( ' ', '', $event_club );
    $event_club = strtolower( $event_club );

    // Формирование названия ключа
    $key        = 'grz_competitions_years_' . strtolower( $event_club );

    // Добавление опции в БД
    set_transient( $key, $start_date, 0 );
}
```